# Overwrite existing csv file using vba

Tags: vba

When I use this vba code to save a newly created csv file, I get a dialogue box asking whether I should overwrite an existing csv file that has the same file name.  How do I always get the new csv file to overwrite an existing file (if it exists)?:

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strOutput, FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strOutput, FileFormat:=xlCSV

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JAL, I don't think any further text is needed here. Of course the answer is quite short but self-explaining.